# Sum Decode statement SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I am trying to sum a few `Decode` statements and column names, but am having difficulties.

currently it is showing as

```
 rank | name | points
----------------------
  0   | john |   0
  0   | john |  40
  1   | john |  30
  2   | tom  |  22
  0   | tom  |   0
```

I expect to have this result:

```
 rank | name | points
----------------------
  1   | john |  70
  2   | tom  |  22
```

**Query:**

```
Select Rank, Name, Code, Points
  From
   (select 
        decode(Table.name, 'condition1', Table.value) As Points,
        decode(Table.name, 'Condition2', Table.value) As Rank,
        Employee.name as Name,
        Employee.GA1 as Code
      from Table
      inner Join Employee
         on Empolyee.positionseq = name.positionseq
      where Table.name IN ('Condition1', 'Condition2')
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select MAX(Rank), Name, Code, SUM(Points)
From
(select 
  decode(Table.name, 'condition1', Table.value) As Points
  decode(Table.name, 'Condition2', Table.value) As Rank
  ,Employee.name as Name
  ,Employee.GA1 as Code
from Table
inner Join Employee
on Employee.positionseq = name.positionseq
where Table.name IN( 'Condition1', 'Condition2'))
GROUP BY Employee.id;
```

I added the `SUM`, `MAX` (for rank) and `GROUP BY` statements. Also corrected some misspellings (Empolyee)

Answer (score 0):

I may be understanding your question incorrectly, however, it seems like you are trying to do the following (omitting inner join for simplicity):

```
Select MAX(rank), name, SUM(points)
FROM UserRanks
GROUP BY name
```

Based on your data set above, you should get the following results:

```
rank name  points

1   john  70
2   tom   22
```